# How to add script underneath categorical ticks in matplotlib / seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have an interesting formatting request.

How would I add these "subcategories" into a categorical label?

My data is formatted as so:

```
Category    Subcategory     Hue     Value
Category 1  Subcategory 1   item_x  10
Category 2  Subcategroy 2   item_y  8
Category 3  Subcategory 3   item_x  6
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using `pyplot`:

```
tick_labels = ['Category 1','\n\nSubcategory 1', 'Category 2','\n\nSubcategory 2', 'Category 3','\n\nSubcategory 3')
tick_locations = np.arange(1, 4)
plt.xticks(tick_locations, tick_labels)
```